# problem using erase function for a vector in c++ "No Matching Function"

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

The code is about finding the sum of first x prime numbers and I am using Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. I haven't seen any tutorial for code, I just studied the concept and trying to implement on my own.
I need to delete the elements from the vector, for which I can use erase. but that's where I'm facing issue.

I searched for function to find the index of a specific element in a vector and it was from algorithm library. It didn't seem to be working, so I wrote a similar function. But the return value of it seems to be not working with erase function of vector.

//this is from main function

```
int f=find(v,t2);
if(f!=-1)
    v.erase(f);
k++;
t2=t*k;
```

//this is the `find` function which returns index

//and here `vi` is `typedef vector<int>`

```
int find (vi v,int val)
{
    int first=0;
    while (v.size()!=first) {
        if (v.at(first)==val) return first;
        ++first;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

as the find function returns an index, it should work according to that and send an index and erase function will use that index and delete element from the index. but it doesn't seem to be working. and  I am getting 
"no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::erase(int&)’".

Comment: If you get an error that the function doesn't exist, you should [check the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) to make sure you are calling it correctly.

Comment: are you sure `find` returns an int?

Comment: use `std::find()` :) if you need a pos you can use then `std::distance()`

Comment: An `int` is not a `std::vector::const_iterator` (and cannot be implicitly converted to one).

Comment: In comments you complain about the answers not working for you. I suggest you include a full code sample (with includes and with using namespace directives / declarations). Without your code it's basically impossible to understand what goes wrong in your specific example.

Answer (score 3):

```
iterator erase (const_iterator position);

iterator erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

There is no erase function that takes an int

And since this doesnt seem to be a homework, there is no point in writing your own `find()`. Use this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Here is a minimal example of how it works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void remove(std::vector<int> &vec, int number) {
    vec.erase(std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), number));
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  vec.push_back(11);
  vec.push_back(22);
  vec.push_back(33);

  remove(vec, 22);

  for (int i : vec) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

[Run it](https://repl.it/repls/PastelAgonizingSign)

Comment: as i have written, algorithm library function find() didn't work. 
i used  
v.erase(find (v.begin(), v.end(), t2));

it said 
"error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, int&)'"

and i didnt forget including the header algorithm file.

Comment: If thats a cite you forgot the namespace, its std::find(...) and you forgot the second iterator which marks the end of your container

Comment: i have written using namespace std; at the beginning. and if i think i am correct v.end() marks the end of the container. but if its not the case then didn't understand second iterator thing. it'd be nice of you if you can explain.

Comment: I added a minimal example that I verified in an online compiler

Answer (score 1):

The member function `erase` accepts as an argument one or two iterators.

So this call

```
v.erase(f);
```

where `f` is an integer is invalid.

Also what is the reason to use your own bad-witten function `find` instead of the standard algorithm `std::find`?

The first code snippet can be rewitten the following way

```
auto it = std::find( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), t2 );

if ( it != std::end( v ) ) v.erase( it );
//...
```

Or if the compiler supports C++ 17 then

```
if ( auto it = std::find( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), t2 ); it != std::end( v ) )
{
    v.erase( it );
}
// ...
```

If you indeed need to write your own function `find` then it can look for example the following way

```
using vi = std::vector<int>;

vi::size_type find( const vi &v, const int &val )
{
    vi::size_type i = 0;

    while ( i != v.size() && v[i] != val ) ++i;

    return i;
}
```

and can be called like

```
auto pos = find( v, t2 );

if ( pos != v.size() ) v.erase( std::next( std::begin( v ), pos ) );
```

Comment: but man find() is not working that's problem too. 
otherwise i would have used it.
now i understood that we cant pass integer for erase. any other way> as using find() says 

"error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, int&)'"

Comment: @captainShoo50 Why is not std::find working? I have shown an example of using it. Can you just reproduce it?